# Exchange 2010 - programmatically insert appointment to public folder calendar

Tags: exchange-server, office-interop

I've run into something that I believe is impossible (from the server side): inserting a calendar appointment into a calendar which is in a public folder.

There are 3 ways I know of to insert an appointment to an outlook calendar

1. EWS managed api - this does not support public folders very well and has a bug which cannot be worked around.  I believe this is attributed to Microsoft's careless decision to move away from supporting public folders and push people to sharepoint.  the api does indeed easily insert appointments into the default calendars, though (useless for my need).
2. WebDAV - another careless decision by Microsoft was to disable WebDAV support for Exchange 2010.  They instead push people to EWS (which has a fatal bug).
3. Outlook interop files - as far as I know cannot be run from the server side.  I suspect this may be my best bet if I can get this working somehow.

Has anyone run into this need before?  How can I get around this?!

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to others here if you can point out what the bug is with EWS managed API when used against public folders

Answer (score 0):

I believe Exchange MAPI/CDO will allow you to do this. What do you mean by Outlook interop files, Outlook MAPI?

Have a look at this brialliant library that wraps MAPI / CDO for exchange as well as Outlook MAPI: http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/